# What kind of SSL shall I use in an Apache web server for serving clients only connected via VPN? Is it enough to use self-signed certificate?

Tags: linux, vpn, apache-http-server

The Apache server is on Ubuntu 20.04. LTS and installed on one client machine connected to the same VPN tunnel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a problem that really has nothing to do with a VPN. The question is really about how to properly configure your Apache server so that web pages aren’t flagged for SSL problems in the user’s browser. The mechanisms through which are already documented and are not related to if the connection is over VPN or not. Look up using self-signed SSL certificates and decide for yourself if they meet your requirements.

Comment: Appleoddity: Thank you for your answer. I thought, that as VPN already establishes secured tunnel between two machines connected to the same VPN network, there should even no need for SSL at all, for exchanging data between web server and client browser. But for the sake of having ssl. connection, the self-signed one will be enough. At least this is what I think, but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you / your comments are correct, you already have a secure connection via VPN, so there is no need to encrypt the data between webserver and browser as well. It would be enough to just use HTTP.

If you want to use HTTPS anyway it should be enough to use a self signed certificate. It still will give you the same encryption as a CA signed certificate would. The main difference is the missing possibility to verify that the certificate actually belongs to the domain (and the security warning shown by the browser). I don't see any need for that and your use case (since the VPN access is in public in the first place) but that's ultimately something for you to decide.

An alternative would be for example to use a [let's encrypt certificate](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/p/lets-encrypt-vs-comodo-ca-which-one-is-right-for-your-website/).

I would recommend reading up on self-signed versus CA certificates, there are plenty of sources ([e.g. here](https://comodosslstore.com/resources/self-signed-certificate-vs-ca-certificate-which-ones-right-for-me/)).

Comment: Albin, thank you very much for your kind answer. Helped a lot!

Comment: @TamásLászló your welcome, if it helped, please consider accepting it as an answer.